# Losing Blue Card upon pay cut

Tags: blue-card

Do I lose my Blue Card if my salary drops below the threshold, due to any reason like changing jobs, or getting a pay cut? Or is it going to stay valid until the expire date for as long as I am still employed?

Comment: What does your zusatzblatt say? If it names a specific company, you need to ask for permission to change jobs with the Auslanderamt, and they might say no due to several reasons like salary.

Comment: I believe I don't have this "additional sheet", just a card. I work in the Netherlands.

Comment: Ah yes I assumed Germany, it should work similarly in the Netherlands, maybe you should see this: https://ind.nl/en/Documents/Which_amount_applies_to_my_highly_skilled_migrant.pdf , then a better question is, how long have you had the blue card?

Comment: Almost 4 years. That document seems to give a clue, though it is still a bit fuzzy.